# Facebook Logout button in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am trying to create an asp.net web application, in which when user logins with Facebook through my application, the friends of that user will be displayed in the application.

Now i want to create a Facebook Logout button so that user can log out also. I tried one code

HTML:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgLogout" runat="server" OnClientClick="FB_Logout()"     ImageUrl="~/logout.jpg"/>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function FB_Logout() {

alert('Are you sure?')
FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect("http://localhost:2708/List.aspx");

}

</script>
```

it was working fine. But now user can not logout. Clicking on Facebook Login Button directly opens the already logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be using an old SDK.

According to the recent JS SDK you would use FB.logout

as in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Also because you want to redirect you could either redirect straight after the logout code with

```
window.location='';
```

or hook on the logout event in Facebook and do the redirect. e.g.

```
 FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function() {window.location = '/users/logout'});
{$callback}
```

Comment: The example on the page I linked to details it. 

FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});

Do what ever code you want inside the function.

Comment: Isha .. mohali ? i hope not every body inderstand thiss